# How would I make these parts of this pocket watch?

Tags: modeling

You guys have been super helpful so like the neighborhood cat who you fed once... I'm back for more. I'm wondering how I would do these two parts of this stop watch. Specifically that sharp curve that comes up from the body and the handle that the chain clasps on to. I have an idea on how to do the gear turning knob and the two structures on either side of it, but if you want to show me the technique to mold those I won't be unhappy. I'm trying to learn proper technique since I've only been using Blender for two weeks now. Don't want to get any bad habits. Thanks again!

[image]

Comment: I would suggest having a go and coming back here if you run into trouble with a specific problem.

Comment: I just don't know how to approach it. I'm not sure what mesh to start with and what methods to use it.